# What settings should I use with my TZ10 at ice hockey?

Tags: sports, camera-settings, panasonic

I have a TZ10. What is the best setting to have the camera on for taking photos at ice hockey without the flash and red eye reduction coming on? Do I need to put in my own settings? If so how?

Answer (score 3):

The Panasonic DMC-ZS7 / TZ10 has a sports mode. You could try that. You could also try Aperture Priority AE mode, select the largest aperture possible at the focal length you choose(F3.3 - 4.9). You could also adjust the ISO sensitivity higher, but not too high that the amount of noise or grain is too much for you. A high value would be ISO 800 or 1600, but your camera also offers High Sensitivity Mode : Auto (1600 - 6400) which you can try.